# How do I select dropdown option in RSelenium?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rselenium

I am trying to scrape https://webgate.ec.europa.eu/competition/transparency/public/search/results and am stuck in the second page after selecting countries.
I would like to select from the dropbox objectives - Regional Aid Scheme, SMEs and Aid for Start ups.

Here's the code so far -

```
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4445L, extraCapabilities = fprof )
remDr$open()


#regular r vest






## Downloading Cartels

remDr$navigate("https://webgate.ec.europa.eu/competition/transparency/public?lang=en")  # load search page 
morereviews <- remDr$findElements(using = "css", "#selectAll") 
morereviews[[1]]$clickElement()
morereviews <- remDr$findElements(using = "css", ".button-search")  
morereviews[[1]]$clickElement()
morereviews <- remDr$findElements(using = "css", "#currency-EUR")  
morereviews[[1]]$clickElement()
remDr$screenshot(display = TRUE)
```

Follow this, I am able to click the dropbox but not able to select the options, any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ui element is ment for typing so you can do:

```
library(RSelenium)
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4444)
remDr$open()

remDr$navigate("https://webgate.ec.europa.eu/competition/transparency/public?lang=en")  # load search page 
morereviews <- remDr$findElements(using = "css", "#selectAll") 
morereviews[[1]]$clickElement()
morereviews <- remDr$findElements(using = "css", ".button-search")  
morereviews[[1]]$clickElement()
morereviews <- remDr$findElements(using = "css", "#currency-EUR")  
morereviews[[1]]$clickElement()

morereviews <- remDr$findElements(using = "css", "#objectives-input") 
morereviews[[1]]$clickElement()
morereviews[[1]]$sendKeysToElement(list("reg", selKeys$down_arrow, selKeys$enter))
morereviews[[1]]$sendKeysToElement(list("sme", selKeys$down_arrow, selKeys$enter))
morereviews[[1]]$sendKeysToElement(list("aid for start", selKeys$down_arrow, selKeys$enter))
remDr$screenshot(display = TRUE)
```

[image]